# Cython function declarations when function steals a reference

Tags: python, cython, python-c-api

There are some Python C-API functions that steal a reference for one passed argument for example [`PyList_SetItem`](https://docs.python.org/c-api/list.html#c.PyList_SetItem), while others increment the reference counts of the argument, for example [`PyList_Append`](https://docs.python.org/c-api/list.html#c.PyList_Append).

Can I tell Cython that the reference will be stolen? Or do I need to use `Py_INCREF` manually?

```
from cpython.object cimport PyObject
from cpython.ref cimport Py_INCREF

cdef extern from "Python.h":
    void PyList_SetItem(object list, Py_ssize_t i, object o)

cpdef void func(list lst, object item):
    Py_INCREF(item)
    PyList_SetItem(lst, 0, item)
```

I know that if a function returns a borrowed references one can change the return type (`PyObject *` for borrowed references, `object` for not-borrowed ones):

```
from cpython.object cimport PyObject
from cpython.ref cimport Py_INCREF

cdef extern from "Python.h":
    PyObject* PyList_GetItem(object list, Py_ssize_t index)
    object PyObject_GetItem(object o, object key)
```

But that doesn't seem to work for stolen references (or was my thinking just wrong?):

```
from cpython.object cimport PyObject

cdef extern from "Python.h":
    void PyList_SetItem(object list, Py_ssize_t i, PyObject *o)

cpdef void func(list lst, object item):
    PyList_SetItem(lst, 0, <PyObject*>item)
```

Comment: This is a great question. Am also interested to learn how this should be solved. Have raised [GH-2722]( https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/2722 ) to figure out how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way for handling "stealing" in Cython [(yet?)](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/2722), so one has to fall back to somewhat awkward manual handling (as pointed out in the question itself):

```
%%cython
from cpython.ref cimport Py_INCREF
from cpython.list cimport PyList_SetItem

def replace(list lst, object item):
    Py_INCREF(item) # prepare for stealing 
    PyList_SetItem(lst, 0, item)
```

With behavior as expected:

```
import sys
a, b= float(), float()
lst = [a]
print(sys.getrefcount(a), sys.getrefcount(b))
# refcount(a)=3 and refcount(b)=2
replace(lst, b)
print(sys.getrefcount(a), sys.getrefcount(b))
# refcount(a)=3 and refcount(b)=2
```

Comment: This answer is a step to make this Q&A to a possible duplicate target.