# Cython Function giving segmentation Fault when calling from Python

Tags: python-3.x, segmentation-fault, cython

So i'm trying to make a script which will clone some value in a 2d- Matrix and since the matrix could be huge, i'm using cython btw i'm new to cython. Here's the code

```py
from cpython cimport *

def cloningNodes(matrix,toClone):
    cdef Py_ssize_t matrixSize=PyList_Size(matrix),cloneSize=PyList_Size(toClone),newSize=matrixSize+cloneSize,i,j
    output=PyList_New(newSize)
    for i in range(matrixSize):
        PyList_SET_ITEM(output,i,
            <object>PyList_GET_ITEM(matrix,i))
        for j in range(cloneSize):
            currentRow=<object>PyList_GET_ITEM(output,i)
            PyList_Append(currentRow,<object>PyList_GET_ITEM(
                    <object>PyList_GET_ITEM(matrix,i),PyLong_AsSsize_t(<object>PyList_GET_ITEM(toClone,j))
                )
            )
    for i in range(cloneSize):
        PyList_SET_ITEM(output,i+matrixSize,<object>PyList_GET_ITEM(output,PyLong_AsSsize_t(<object>PyList_GET_ITEM(toClone,i))))
    return output
```

After Compiling and calling this module with

```py
from MODULE_NAME import cloningNodes
cloningNodes([[1,2],[2,1]],[1])
```

it's giving me segmentation Fault(CoreDumped)
Can anyone tell me why is this giving Segmentation Fault along with any minor improvements you could think of.

Edit: Btw i tried to put a print statement before return output and it seems like the list is created without a problem but there's some problem while returning the list.

Comment: It's to do with stolen and borrowed references. Suggested "minor" improvements would be to avoid using lists of lists as a matrix, and probably to start by writing it in simple Python instead of the the Python C API

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/41925500/5769463 for the way how borrowed stealed references should be handled.

Comment: ead and David thanks for the suggestions using Py_INCREF before PyList_SET_ITEM worked.